# Not able to get storage variable on another class app.component.ts in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage

I am working on ionic version 3.20.0 application.

In that, I have feature for login with Facebook.

After user login with facebook successfully, I am setting storage variable in `login.ts` with `this.storage.set('picture', data['picture']['data']['url']);`

I am able to get this picture variable in other file called dashboard.ts with below code successfully

```
 storage.get('picture').then((imagestore) => {
      console.log(imagestore);
      if(imagestore){ console.log("IF call");
          this.profilePhoto = imagestore;
     }else{
         this.profilePhoto = "./assets/images/profile.png";
          console.log("Else call");
      }     
    });
```

But I am not able to get picture storage variable in `app.components.ts`.

Below is my app.components.ts file

> import { Component, ViewChild }
>   from '@angular/core'; import { Platform, MenuController, Nav, App }
>   from 'ionic-angular'; import { SplashScreen } from
>   '@ionic-native/splash-screen'; import { StatusBar } from
>   '@ionic-native/status-bar'; import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
>   import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from
>   '@ionic-native/facebook';
>
> import { SecureStorage } from '@ionic-native/secure-storage'; import {
>   LandingPage } from '../pages/landing/landing'; import { DashboardPage
>   } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard'; import { MarketPage } from
>   '../pages/market/market'; import { ImagePicker } from
>   '@ionic-native/image-picker';
>
> @Component({    selector: 'app-root',   templateUrl: 'app.html' })
>   export class MyApp { 
>       @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;   public name: any;   public fbphotoshidden: any;   public firstName: any;   public profilePhoto:
>   any;
>
> pages: Array<{title: string, icon: string, component: any}>;
>   pushPages: Array<{title: string, icon: string, component: any}>;
>
> constructor(
>
> ```
> platform: Platform,
> private secureStorage: SecureStorage,
> private storage: Storage,
> public menu: MenuController,
> private fb: Facebook,
> public app: App,
> public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
> public statusBar: StatusBar,
> public imagePicker: ImagePicker
> ```
>
> ) {
>
> ```
> platform.ready().then(() => {
>   // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
>   // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
>   this.splashScreen.hide();
>   this.statusBar.styleDefault();
>   this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
>
>   this.secureStorage.create('jeffrey').then(
>     () => {
>       console.log("Secure Storage is ready");
>     },
>     (error) => {
>       //there should be screen lock available in your application with pin or pattern
>       console.log(error);
>     }
>   );
>
> });
>
>
> storage.get('firstName').then((store) => {
>
>         if(store){
>             this.firstName = store;
>         }
>
>     });
> console.log("Storage Picture");   console.log( storage.get('picture'));
> storage.get('picture').then((imagestore) => {
>   console.log(imagestore);
>   if(imagestore){         console.log("IF call");
>       this.profilePhoto = imagestore;
>   }else{
>       this.profilePhoto = "./assets/images/profile.png";
>       console.log("Else call");
>   }
>
> });
> storage.get('login').then((store) => {
>
>   if(store){ 
>     this.nav.setRoot(DashboardPage); 
>   }else{
>     this.nav.setRoot(LandingPage); 
>   }
>
> });
> ```
>
> }
>
> async selectImage(){
>       let options = {
>         // max images to be selected, defaults to 15. If this is set to 1, upon
>         // selection of a single image, the plugin will return it.
>         maximumImagesCount: 1,
>
> ```
>   // max width and height to allow the images to be.  Will keep aspect
>   // ratio no matter what.  So if both are 800, the returned image
>   // will be at most 800 pixels wide and 800 pixels tall.  If the width is
>   // 800 and height 0 the image will be 800 pixels wide if the source
>   // is at least that wide.
>   //width: 100,
>   //height: 100,
>
>   // quality of resized image, defaults to 100
>   //quality: 100
> };
>
> const [imageSource] = await this.imagePicker.getPictures(options);
> this.storage.set('picture', imageSource.replace('file://', ''));
> console.log(this.profilePhoto);
> ```
>
> }   goHome(){
>       this.menu.close();
>       this.nav.setRoot(DashboardPage);   }
>        goToMarket(){
>       this.menu.close();
>       this.nav.setRoot(MarketPage);   }
>
> checkFbLogin(){
>       this.fb.getLoginStatus().then((status: FacebookLoginResponse) =>{
>
> ```
>   let login = status.status;
>   if(login == 'connected'){
>
>       this.storage.get('picture').then((pic) => {
>
>           if(pic){
>               this.profilePhoto = pic;
>           }else{
>               this.profilePhoto = "./assets/images/profile.png";
>           }
>
>       });
>
>   }else{
>          this.profilePhoto = "./assets/images/profile.png";
>   }
>
> })
>
> }
> ```
>
> openPage(page) {
>       // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
>       this.menu.close();
>       // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
>       this.nav.setRoot(page.component);   }
>
> logout(event){
>          this.menu.close();
>         this.storage.clear();
>         this.nav.setRoot(LandingPage);   }
>
> pushPage(page) {
>       // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
>       this.menu.close();
>
> ```
> this.app.getRootNav().push(page.component);
> ```
>
> } }

Comment: can you share your app component.ts file? did you import storage in there?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko i have added  app.component.ts file code in my question, please have a look. Thanks in advance.